# Is it bad to update a job application after the due date?

Tags: job-search

I am graduating from a math PhD program next May, so I am on the job market now. I have already submitted some applications (via mathjobs.org). But most applications are due in the next week or so and I have been working on my research statement quite a lot. Now I've made many changes since the version that I submitted.

So my question is: would it be bad to upload a new version of my research statement to jobs that I already applied to and whose first deadline has past? 
Most job ads say that applications submitted before the first deadline will receive full consideration. I don't want to risk begin omitted from that group by updating my application.

Thanks for any replies or comments!

Comment: I suspect it's pretty common: after all, most people have just 1 version of their RS, which they keep updating for as long as there are jobs they're applying to; but some of the deadlines will already have passed at the time they're updating it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not "bad" to update your application after the deadline, but based on all the committees I've been on, the odds are low that your revised version will be looked at. What most of us do is download the full set of applications shortly after the deadline, and then start to read them. We don't go back and look to see if the applications have changed, and even if we wanted to spend time doing this, I don't think it would be fair to all applicants. (And please don't email that your application has changed, unless it's something amazingly important, like your recent Nobel prize!) All that said, it won't hurt anything to update your application, but your time is likely better spent doing other things.